# File was not found error when deploying a .NET app with Bitbucket piplines to Azure App Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, bitbucket

I followed [this](https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-an-aspnetcore-from-bitbucket/) tutorial to set a pipeline to my .NET 6 API but I'm getting the following error:

```
+ dotnet restore
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.412/NuGet.targets(369,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/laso-api.domain/laso-api.Domain.csproj" was not found. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/laso-api.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.412/NuGet.targets(369,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/laso-api.application/laso-api.Application.csproj" was not found. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/laso-api.sln]
```

Here it is my bitbucket pipelines file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:6.0

pipelines:
  default:
  - step:
      name: Build and Test
      caches:
        - dotnetcore
      script:
        - REPORTS_PATH=./test-reports/build_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
        - dotnet restore
        - dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release
        - dotnet test --no-build --configuration Release --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=$REPORTS_PATH/junit.xml"
  - step:
      name: Lint the code
      caches:
        - dotnetcore
      script:
        - export SOLUTION_NAME=laso-api
        - export REPORTS_PATH=linter-reports
        - dotnet new tool-manifest
        - dotnet tool install JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools
        - dotnet tool restore
        - dotnet jb inspectcode ${SOLUTION_NAME}.sln --output="${REPORTS_PATH}/jb-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}.xml" --build
      artifacts:
        - linter-reports/**
```

File structure:

[image]

Comment: The sln file may not be generated or in a different folder.  First manually find the csproj files for the two sln files.  Then double click on the csproj filename.  The SLN should be generated when project is opened.  See if error is resolved.  If not the main csproj file needs to be edited (it is text) and correct the location of the sln file which is in a different folder. You will have to locate where the sln is located.